# D3 pie chart transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm studying transitions in D3js, trying to get them working with a simple pie chart that is derived from [a Mike Bostock example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410).

I want to transition the data in the pie from data to data2, but the chart does not update.

This is the transition statement:

```
path.selectAll("path").data(pie(data2)).transition().duration(2000);
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I've got it working with the below. Now I'd like to understand why this is working. I understand the .attr("d",arc) part, but why do I need to selectAll("path")?

```
path.selectAll("path").data(pie(data2)).transition().duration(2000).attr("d",arc);
```

***END EDIT***

The complete code ([JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/x8fe4g0x/4/)):

```
var width = 200,
    height = 200,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category20();
var data = [2, 19, 18, 99, 100];
var data2 = [100, 1200, 20, 88, 12];

var pie, arc, svg, path, data;

var chartCanvas = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


var path = chartCanvas
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");



function setupPieChart() {

    pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .sort(null);

    arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - 100)
        .outerRadius(radius - 20)

    path
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
            return color(i);
        })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .each(function (d) {
                        this._current = d;
        }); // store the initial angles
    console.log(path);

}

setupPieChart();

console.log(path);

path.selectAll("path").data(pie(data2)).transition().duration(2000);
```

Comment: There is a noticeable difference between Mike Bostock's example and yours. His does provide a [`attrTween()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#attrTween) callback which is responsible for transitioning the path's `d` attribute corresponding to the new data values. Since your code is missing this function, there is no way for D3 to determine what exactly you want to transition.

Comment: @altocumulus, thanks, I changed that. Why do I need to .selectAll("path") though to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I immediately see you are missing some important part of the update process. You copied the original code, but you forgot the update part :-). I can tell, because I see in your code you store the initial angles.

Look again at the code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) and try to understand the function arcTween. More information can be found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636). You need an arc tween function to calculate the new angles based on the initial angles (which is why you stored the initial angles in the first place :-).

I won't do the fiddle at the moment, cause in my experience, you learn more if you try to understand the arc tween function (as I did [here](http://www.facet-it.be/cv/experiences.html) . This is a link to a personal project of mine, but feel free to copy code as  you see fit).

You need to .selectAll("path") as those are the actual elements that will update. When doing d3, try to think of the chart elements as following: Elements that are not visible yet (which is enter collection), elements that are visible now (which can be seen as the update collection) and elements that can be removed (the exit collection).

You need to see those elements based on the data you want to visualize. D3 is data driven documents, so everything is in relation to the data you want to show on the screen: if you have data but no elements yet, you do an "enter" of elements. So you do a selection of elements that are not in the DOM yet, but will soon be, because you will bind them to the data you have.

If you already have elements on the screen, and the number of elements matches the data you need to show (for example: var data = [20 ,30 , 40], you got 3 pieces of data here for 3 div's on the screen, you got a matching amount), then d3 will update your selection (hence the update collection or update selection) so the elements properties match the data.

If you have more elements on the screen then there is data to show, then you can do an exit of elements (again, hence the exit selection or collection). I hope that made it a bit more clear and that it made sense as well :-)

Comment: True, I figured the attr("d",arc) part and updated the transition statement. Thanks for all the links in your post; they will help me to gain a deeper understanding!

Comment: This block (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636) is extremely helpful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: added some explanation as to the why you need to select those path elements :-)

Answer (score 2):

`.transition` starts a [transition](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) for the attributes change(s) declared after it. You don't set / do anything after `.transition`, so there is nothing to interpolate over. In the original example from Mike, you'll see he sets the `d` attribute after starting the transition, specifying a [custom interpolator (`arcTween`)](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#attrTween)